# ember app kit can't find .jshintrc

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, bower, jshint

I'm trying to get started with [ember-app-kit](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/guides/getting-started.html) I wget the master.zip from github and unzip it. I moved the directory contents to another that I have named for my project. Then run `npm install` and `bower install`. But when I run grunt server I get

```
ERROR: Can't find config file: .jshintrc


    Warning:  Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
%
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `cp -r <src> <dest>` to include dotfiles. **That will include subdirectories.**

To copy both regular and dot files you can use `cp <src>.* <src>* <dest>`

Answer (score 3):

ugh, turns out when I copied the directory over the hidden files didn't get copied
`cp ember-app-kit-master/* myProject`.
I ran
`cp ember-app-kit-master/.* myProject` to get the hidden files. Note the dot-star.